# Create Synonyms From Natural Language Processing in Python

Tags: python, nlp, large-language-model

I'm investigating common interests in people throughout my organisation and want to fine tune my process.  My aim is to have a weighted graph of common and uncommon interests amongst a relatively disparate group of people based on their stated interests.  I've used a range of processes in python to do a rather rough version of interest mapping.  So far, my algorithm looks like this:

1. Download their profile from the internet using the requests library.
2. Extract the relevant information from the HTML using Beutiful Soup
3. Analyse the text for keywords using a combination of Spacy (en_core_web_sm) and LLM (distilroberta-base) and using Counter() to get a count of each occurrence. (lemmatize then tokenize, detach embeddings, evaluate distance using cosine similarity, count occurrences)
4. Filter based on unnecessary keywords
5. Return a dictionary with an id and a list of interests
6. Iterate for each profile getting a list of id's with common interests
7. Transform the output from 6 so that the interests are the id, and the common id's are the interests.
8. Graph output from 6 using plotly and streamlit
9. Graph output 7 using plotly and streamlit (shown)

The process works quite well in that I can generate a graph of interests based on keywords people use in their profile.  The problem is that people are inherently different in their choice of words.  There are common topics that should be grouped together and I wonder if there's an LLM (or similar) way of clustering keywords.  For example ['climate', 'decarbonization'] might be grouped as one, 'climate' or in the sample dictionary Python, R and Java may be collapsed to Programming.

Importantly, this needs to be done dynamically as I intend to add and remove users as I need to.

I've been scanning huggingface for different transformers that might be useful but I'm a relative newbie to that topic and was hoping that someone could point me towards either a good model or package that can help.

```
#sample output from step 3
    {'id': chris,
     'interests': {'Python':3, 'R':2, 'Java': 1}
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Quick update: I've tried using the synsets from nltk.corpus.wordnet but the synonyms there are too specific for my usage.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a topic modelling framework to group users interest into a general ontologyy such as: programming, methematics, etc.

I would recommend you a framework like this blogpost (easy to follow and well explained)

[image]
source: [Clustering Contextual Embeddings for Topic Modelling](https://towardsdatascience.com/clustering-contextual-embeddings-for-topic-model-1fb15c45b1bd))

Let give you some recommendations:

## 1. Embedding model

1. Choose the encoder model based on the downstream task and the corpus. Depending on that, the model will cluster together some words or others. In your case, general topic modelling, I would look for models trained on wikipedia/twitter corpus such as BERT variants.
2. Consider also the size of the embedding compared to the data:

- the greater the size the more information (better clusters) but the greater computation time (poor performance/expensive)
- the smaller the size the less information but faster computations.

As an starting point, I recommend you a well-known model for semantic
search and clustering available in hugging face: [all-MiniLM-L6-v2](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2)

## 2. Clustering

Choose a method that clusters together embeddings based on cosine distance or euclidean distance. I would go ahead with K-Means on the first go.

But maybe you would want to explore hierarchical methods (if you want to control embeddings linkage) or DBSCAN (if you think that topics may be dense zones in the space and discard noise)

## 3. Ontology Usage

Once the topics have been discovered, let is say you got 20 clusters: Programming, Management, Busines, etc. You will need to use a classification modelling to automate the task of classifying new tags into one ontology.

Here you have several options:

1. Add a classification layer to an encoder. You can do it with Hugging face: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/en/tasks/sequence_classification
2. Use a conventional machine learning model. KNN seems the fastest and reliable model, as it assign a new word to the closest topic center. But you can choose the most suitable for you.

Comment: Daniel, thanks again for taking the time to write it out and sorry for not being quicker at rating your reply.  I've managed to implement some of the bits you suggested (I'm up to part 3 now) but I've less time than I hoped.  This solution looks really promising so thanks again!

Comment: Nice! Thanks, if you get stucked somewhere in the process donnot hesitate to ask for details! :)